# How to make a module act as package with __path__ variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I was trying to dig deep into python `import` mechanism and came across this in the  [Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#packages) section of the documentation:

> It’s important to keep in mind that all packages are modules, but not all modules are packages. Or put another way, packages are just a special kind of module. Specifically, any module that contains a `__path__` attribute is considered a package.

It looks interesting but I could not find any example demonstrating this!
So, how to actually implement it?
In real world scenarios do you ever need such implementation?

Comment: You do not implement this. You create packages as usual, which automatically implement this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually creating a "package" by setting `__path__` would be a really weird thing to do, and I've never seen a use case for it. The import system core should handle it correctly, but code that expects "normal" packages is likely to break in all sorts of exotic ways. You **probably shouldn't do this**.

That said, what you're asking for would be as simple as putting

```
__path__ = ['whatever', 'list', 'of', 'directories', 'you', 'want']
```

in the module you want Python to treat as a package. Python will then treat the module as a package, and look for submodules in the directories specified in your artificial `__path__`.

For example, if you have the following directory structure:

```
.
├── contents
│   └── submodule.py
└── package.py
```

where `package.py` contains

```
import os

__path__ = [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'contents')]
```

and `contents/submodule.py` contains

```
x = 3
```

then `import package.submodule` will treat `package.py` as a package and `contents/submodule.py` as the `package.submodule` submodule of the `package` package, and `package.submodule.x` will resolve to `3`.